# avoiding duplicate entries and caching entered form values

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have some code that controls duplicate entries in particular the USER ID. it checks in the database at submit and if that USER ID exists already it gives that notification. now the problem is when i submit  and if that USER ID entered already exists in the database, all the other entries on the form are cleared, prompting me to re_enter all the other details again. i find this annoying and retrogressive. i want some help on how better i can do it such that only the USER ID text box returns empty, keeping other details safe/unchanged or indeed alternatively keeping/buffering/caching all details previously entered so that i can also review the duplicate USER ID before changing it.

new_user.php

```
        <h1 align="center">Create New User</h1>
        <p align="center" style="color:#F00"><?php if(isset($_GET['dup'])){ echo "That User ID Already Exists!"; } ?>&nbsp;</p>
           <form id="form1" method="post" action="add_user.php">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                <td width="204"><div align="right">User ID:</div></td>
                <td width="286">
                  <input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" />
               </td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="right">Full Names:</div></td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="right">Gender:</div></td>
                      <td><select id="sex" name="sex">
                      <option selected="selected" value="male">Male</option>
                      <option name="female">Female</option>
                      </select></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="right">NRC Number:</div></td>
                      <td>
                      <input type="number" name="nrcno" id="nrcno" min="1"  />
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="right">Phone Number:</div></td>
                      <td>
                      <input type="number" name="cellno" id="cellno" />
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="right">Email Address:</div></td>
                      <td>
                      <input type="email" name="emailad" id="emailad" />
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><div align="right">Position Held:</div></td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" name="posh" id="posh" />
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="create" id="create" value="Add User" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
          </form>
```

add_user.php

```
        <?php
        $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $sex= $_POST['sex'];
        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $nrcno = $_POST['nrcno'];
        $cellno= $_POST['cellno'];
        $emailad = $_POST['emailad'];
        $posh = $_POST['posh'];


        require("get_func.php");

        checkID($id);

        include("connect.php");

        mysql_select_db("ceec", $con);

        $query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('$user_id', '$fname', '$sex','$name', '$nrcno', '$cellno', '$emailad', '$posh')";

        if (mysql_query($query)){

            header("Location: success.php");

            }
        else {echo "Nada" . mysql_error(); }
        mysql_close($con);
                   ?>
```

get_func.php

```
         <?php                      
        function checkID($id){

        include_once("connect.php");

        mysql_select_db("ceec",$con);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = '$id'";

        $result= mysql_query($query);   

        if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

        {
        header("Location: new_user.php?dup=true");
        break;  
        }

        else {}

        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['user_id'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['user_id'];} ?>/>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'. check your code once more

Comment: missed a ) after 'user_id']);} ?>/>

Comment: i noticed bro. but still your code doesn't have any effect. lets try to find more ways.

Comment: user_id wasn't the best example as that is the one you want cleared, do ths on the rest though and they should retain their values.put a span next to the input with an error message set to display none in css,and if isset dup then show the span.

Comment: thats my problem, i want to control the USER ID only. remember i also have another ID which is primary key in the database f=different from USER ID.